# How cross out multiple columns on same row and format cell colour when box ticked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script is able to cross out the first column juste after the the check box, while I'm looking to cross out the whole row.

[image]

Also, I'd like to apply a different colour when the box is ticked.

[image]

```
function onEdit(e){
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var myRange = e.range;
  var mySheetName = mySheet.getSheetName();
  var myStatus = myRange.getValue();
  var currRow = myRange.getRow();
  var currCol = myRange.getColumn();
  var myItem = mySheet.getRange(currRow, currCol + 1);
  if (
    mySheetName === 'Feuille1'
    && currCol === 1
  ) {
    if (
      myStatus
    ) {
      myItem.setFontLine("line-through");
    } else {
      myItem.setFontLine(null);
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Set Line Through

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Feuille1' && e.range.columnStart == 1) {
    let rg = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, sh.getLastColumn() - 1);
    if(e.value == "TRUE") {
      rg.setFontLine('line-through')
    } else {
      rg.setFontLine('none')
    }
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]